# text-transform: uppercase on string containing ß break input text on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I need to show on a lot of input fields with value in uppercase. Using just css `text-transform: uppercase` I encountered a problem with 'ß' char on chrome. It is converted into 'SS'. Chrome doesn't handle change of string length and make impossible to move cursor over last char.

Here is a simple [example of this issue](https://jsbin.com/vuhizimulo/edit?html,css,output). Any way to handle exception of text-transform with just css?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Gro.C3.9Fschreibweise_mit_Ersetzung_von_.C3.9F_durch_SS either the replacing with SS or a lowercase ß (mixed uppercase/lower case) are used. Replacing is the official rule.

Comment: I'm fine with official rule, but chrome doesn't handle length of string transformed. this causes strange behavior. I hope to resolve wihtout js

Comment: Can you please explain this little bit more. Thanks.

Comment: Please open the example on chrome. Focus in input and try to move cursor after last char. Or just try to select input content using ctrl+a. Last char will not be selected.

Comment: If you used Greek letter β (Beta), then it will replace β with  "B" and it will not causing any issue.

Comment: Eszett or 'ß' is not Beta. Uppercase of 'ß' should be 'ß' or 'SS'. I'm not trying to find something that looks similar

Comment: To be pedantic: Uppercase of 'ß' should be 'ẞ' (Unicode U+1E9E). But sadly, the browsers ignore that.